# Will my searches be slow in my database design?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm building a database of IT candidates for a friend who owns a recruitment company. He has a database of thousands of candidates currently in an excel spreadsheet and I'm converting it into  mySQL database.

Each candidate has a skill field with their skills listed as a string e.g. "javascript, php, nodejs..." etc.

My friend will have employees under him who will also search the database, however we want to make it so they are limited to search results with candidates with specific skills depending on what vacancy they are working on for security reasons (so they don't steal large sections of the database and go and setup their own recruitment company with the data).

So if an employee is working on a javascript role, they will be limited to search results where the candidate has the word "javascript" in their skills field. So if they searched for all candidates named "Michael" then it would only return "Michaels" with javascript skills for instance.

My concern is that the searches might take too long if for every search since it must scan the skills field which can sometimes be a long string.

Is my concern justified? If so is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: It will be slow unless you normalise the skills to a separate table, though full text search can help mitigate.... but you haven't once mentioned the word indexes in this description of your design

Comment: I previously had a conversation with my friend and he said that a list of preset skills to choose from for candidates would be too cumbersome in the design as there are too many skills and they are constantly changing.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't normalize your database.... the cross reference doesn't need to be manually maintained but can be modified to add new skills when a new CV is entered onto the system

Comment: The point is that you can't efficiently search for an entry in a comma separated list, even with full text search, and without full text search it requires a full table scan, searching through every single record in the table

Answer (score 1):

If the number of records are in the thousands, you probably won't have any speed issues (just make sure you're not querying more often than you should).

You've tagged this question with a 'mysql' tag so I'm assuming that's the database you're using.  Make sure you add a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) to speed up the search.  Please note, however, that this type of index is only available for INNODB table starting with MySQL 5.6.

Try the builtin search first, but if you find it to be too slow, or not accurate enough in it's results, you can look at external full-text search engines.  I've personally had very good experience with the [Sphinx search server](http://sphinxsearch.com/), where it easily indexed millions of text records and returned good results.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries will require a full table scan (unless you use a full text index).  I highly recommend that you change the data structure in the database by introducing two more tables:  `Skills` and `CandidateSkills`.

The first would be a list of available skills, containing rows such as:

```
SkillId    SkillName
      1    javascript
      2    php
      3    nodejs
```

The second would say which skills each person has:

```
CandidateId    SkillId
     1            1
     2            1
     2            2
```

This will speed up the searches, but that is not the primary reason.  The primary reason is fix problems and enable functionality such as:

- Preventing spelling errors in the list of searchs.
- Providing a basis for enabling synonym searches.
- Making sure thought goes into adding new skills (because they need to be added to the `Skills` table.
- Allowing the database to scale.

If you attempt to do what you want using a full text index, you will learn a few things.  For instance, the default minimum word length is 4, which would be a problem if your skills include "C" or "C++".  MySQL doesn't support synonyms, so you'd have to muck around to get that functionality.  And, you might  get unexpected results if you have have skills that are multiple words.